# Can I use VR controllers as regular pc game controllers?

Tags: controllers, windows-mixed-reality

I really like the Oculus Rift controllers, the feel of them, and the fact that I can hold each of them separately instead of keeping my arms in the same position makes me think it would be awesome for normal use as a PC game controller. Is there a way of doing this with Oculus/HTC/WindowsMR controllers or are there any similar controllers just for PC where they are split?